# "[object Object]" in sails backend

Tags: jquery, ajax, sails.js

I don't know why but at this moment, when I send a Object using jQuery AJAX the server can't obtain the param correctly.

I set dataType='json' in the AJAX request, is necessary additional configuration in sails?

Comment: How are you sending the object?

Comment: How are you determining that's the actual content and not just the toString?

Comment: post your code. Your jQuery post and how your attempting to read the value in sails.

Comment: Guys, the problem is not jQuery, is Quo library (micro librarie compatible with jQuery). Bug explained here => https://github.com/soyjavi/QuoJS/issues/136. Thanks for your time.